# Use Flask Restful Google App Engine with Angular

Tags: python, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to marry this [angular python project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/angular) and this [restful flask project](https://github.com/theacodes/App-Engine-Flask-Restful-Example).

`Directory`

```
- /app
    - css/app.css
    - js/app.js
    - index.html
- app.yaml
- main.py
- appengine_config.py
- vendor.py
- requirements.txt
```

`app.yaml`

```
application: your-application-id-here
version: 1
runtime: python37
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /rest/.*
  script: main.APP

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/.*

- url: /
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
```

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful


APP = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(APP)


class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/rest/query/')


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 404 error."""
    return 'Sorry, Nothing at this URL.', 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 500 error."""
    return 'Sorry, unexpected error: {}'.format(e), 500
```

Everything in the `app/` folder is exactly the same from the python angular project.

If I comment out the following from `app.yaml`, I can access `/rest/query` and get the expected output.

```
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: app/\1
  upload: app/.*

- url: /
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
```

However, when it is not commented out I get a `404` for `/rest/query`. At `/` I am able to see the static `index.html` page, loaded with the angular hooks. No data is populated since `app.js` cannot query `/rest/query`.

How can I set up a GAE Flask restful project that uses Angular?

Comment: Can you show your app's directory structure including the location of the `app.yaml` and `main.py` files?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Edited, if you checkout the links above you will find `appengine_config .py` and `vendor.py`. These basically look towards a generated `/lib` folder in the directory root for dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of this workaround but I moved the routing to happen from `app.yaml` to `main.py`

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext import restful


class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}


app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/rest/query')


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 404 error."""
    return 'Sorry, Nothing at this URL.', 404


@app.errorhandler(500)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 500 error."""
    return 'Sorry, unexpected error: {}'.format(e), 500
```

`app.yaml`

```
application: application-id-here
version: 1
runtime: python37
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

`directory`

```
- /static
    - css/app.css
    - js/app.js
    - partials/...
- /templates/index.html
- app.yaml
- main.py
- appengine_config.py
- vendor.py
- requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I had to do this I deploy a flask api with a database as a web service and stand alone app.

Next you have to add CORS to allow your service to talk to another app, in this case a frontend client using the angular framework.

Then I deploy my angular app that will accept api calls to your backend web service.

My project uses sql server and .net core web api for the web server deployed to azure. And an Angular app deployed to google cloud. I also have another angular app deployed to azure.

I am working on a new api and dB for for my google cloud angular frontend app to make things easier to test and develop.

Comment: My intention is to keep everything small and simple under one GAE project. I'm trying to get over the hurdle where I can run an angular app _or_ rest api, but not both. This must be an `app.yaml` routing issue, right?

Comment: Especially since in the above angular example, you can do so with `webapp2`